# Deep linking by appending the url based on user selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to implement deep linking in a website.
For example, I have a sample website domain.com/
I have 3 check boxes and based on that filter is happening on web page. If i check first check box, content
in web page being filtered with 1st check box values.
Now, my requirement is to update the browser url as well with domain.com/?p1=filter1

Also, If i load the new url, it should directly show me the web page with the first filter already selected and results as per first filter.

I want to implement this using javascript, jquery.

Where do I start and how to implement? Please help.

Comment: Welcome :) Please clarify the point where you want to update the page content and redirect to a new page based on that choice ! You could either redirect to a specific page or same page with parameters... or load the filtered content in the same page. But not both :)

Comment: I want to load the filtered content on the same page and at the same time the url of the page should be appended with filetered parameters.

Comment: There is a "dirty" way of updating URL by using window.history.pushState... Now please could you add some data we could work with ! Please provide static json data instead of Database queries... so it would be easier to make you a fiddle or a working snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. window.history.pushState and window.history.replaceState helped me to do the required job. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Glad that helped you ! You could answer your own question if you like...